# Find/replace in differrent file extensions

Tags: regular-expressions, search, replace

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired+, xah-find

I use package **xah-find** for find/replace text in many files.
OK. It's work.
If I want to find in all java files I use the next regexp:

```
File path regex: \.java\'
```

OK. It's work.
But if I want in files with the next extensions:

```
 .java, .xml, .properties
```

What regexp must be?
'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`xah-find`](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp-xah-find-text.html) uses emacs regular expressions (regexps).

Regexps support [the or operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash) with `\|`. The elisp regexp `\.java\|\.xml` matches `.java` OR `.xml`. Furthermore there are `\(` and `\)` for grouping. Therefore you could choose `\.\(java\|xml\|properties\)\'` as regexp for your special use case.

Side note: If for any reason saving the subexpression of the group has to be avoided one can also use a silent group `\.\(?:java\|xml\|properties\)\'`.